# Pixel 3a XL Requires SIM Card Removed/Reinserted to Power On

Tags: boot, sim-card, power-on, google-pixel-3a-xl

My wife has a Pixel 3a XL, and in the last 2 weeks it has shut down unexpectedly 3 times, refusing to power back on. The battery is charged, and connecting it to any charger makes no difference. Holding the power button for 30 seconds fails also.

The only thing that has fixed it all 3 times is by removing the SIM card and reinserting it. Then pressing the power button, the phone would magically boot up like there was never an issue.

The 2nd time this happened, which was just two days ago, I tried powering it back on with the SIM card removed before reinserting it, yet it would still NOT power on. But as soon as I put the SIM back into the phone, pressed the power button, it powered back on.

I'm thinking the issue is with the SIM card, but then after this test, shouldn't the phone have powered on with the SIM card removed, if it was the SIM card?

This is very confusing to me. Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?